# Are there any good guidelines for building a KVM Cluster on Red Hat

Tags: kvm-virtualization, cluster

I am looking to understand how other people have built clusters of KVM host servers. I am especially interested in how people solved the problem of having them automatically failover if one node dies?

Comment: I have built this tutorial, but the one piece, I really haven't solved is explained above http://crunchtools.com/kvm-cluster-with-drbd-gfs2/

Answer (score 3):

I recommend reading this tutorial:

https://alteeve.com/w/2-Node_Red_Hat_KVM_Cluster_Tutorial

Looking at your blog post the thing you miss is a clustering solution like RHCS or Linux-HA.

Answer (score 0):

it's automated in RHEV

Comment: RHEV still has a Windows only gui so still not an option, plus a completely different cost associated with it, thanks thought.

Comment: If you read the news, the windows-only part is going to be gone. As for everything else, it is of course totally up to you

Comment: Yeah, thanks I read that like 6 months ago, still nothing

Comment: not an easy task, but it's been done. RHEV3 is in public beta, and should be released soon enough

Answer (score 0):

RHEV 3.0 will be released on the second half year of 2011, which will switch from Windows + .net to Linux + Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ovirt, which is the open source version of RHEV.
http://www.ovirt.org/Home
It does HA and live migration. It also supports some OpenStack parts.